# Asymptotics of integral

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, asymptotics

I'm looking at the behavior of the following function
$\Psi\left(\, z\, \right)$ around $0^{+}$ and $+\infty$, and I struggle a bit because of the integrability around $0\ldots$

$$
\Psi\left(\, z\, \right) =
z^{1/2} \int_{0}^{\infty}\ln\left(1 + {\,\mathrm{e}^{-zy} \over y}\right)
\,{\mathrm{d}y \over \,\sqrt{\,\vphantom{\large a} y\, }\,} + 
z^{3/2}\int_{0}^{\infty}\,\sqrt{\,\vphantom{\large a}y\, }\, \ln\left(1 + {\,\mathrm{e}^{-zy} \over y}\right)\,\mathrm{d}y .
$$

If anyone could help me I'd be very happy !.

Comment: Hint: Around $0$, the $\ln$ term is approximately $1/y$, and around $\infty$, approximately $-zy$.

Comment: My naive approach would be to replace $e^{-zy}$ with $\max(0,1-zy)$ if $x$ is close to zero, with $\frac{1}{1+zy}$ if $x$ is large, then compute/approximate the resulting integrals. That is not so difficult. For instance $$\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\log(1+1/y)}{\sqrt{y}}\,dy = 2\pi, \qquad \int_{0}^{+\infty}\log\left(1+\frac{1}{y(y+1)}\right)\sqrt{y}\,dy=\frac{2\pi}{3}.$$

Comment: For $z>0$ and large $y $, the log term is approximately just zero, with an exponentially small correction.

Comment: It is probably useful to exploit integration by parts in order to remove the logarithms and have something more manageable.

Comment: this is a though one...

Answer (score 1):

For $y \ll 1/z$, $e^{-zy}/y=1/y+O(1)$ so that $\ln(1+e^{-zy}/y)=\ln(e^{-zy}/y)+\ln(1+ye^{zy})$. Now $\ln(1/y+O(1))=-\ln(y)+O(y)$. Similarly $\ln(1+ye^{zy})=y+O(y^2)$. Thus $\ln(1+e^{-zy}/y)=-\ln(y)+O(y)$ in that limit.

For $y \gg 1/z$, $\ln(1+e^{-zy}/y)=e^{-zy}/y+O(e^{-2zy})$.

Thus your first integrand behaves like $-\ln(y)y^{-1/2}+O(y^{1/2})$ as $y \to 0$ and like $e^{-zy} y^{-3/2}+O(e^{-2zy})$ as $y \to \infty$. Your second integrand behaves like $-\ln(y) y^{1/2} + O(y^{3/2})$ as $y \to 0$ and like $e^{-zy} y^{-1/2}+O(e^{-2zy})$ as $y \to \infty$. So without diving into the world of composite asymptotic expansions (which can be quite complicated), an approximation can be given as

$$z^{1/2} \left ( \int_0^{a/z} -\ln(y) y^{-1/2} dy + \int_{a/z}^\infty e^{-zy} y^{-3/2} dy \right ) + z^{3/2} \left ( \int_0^{b/z} -\ln(y) y^{1/2} dy + \int_{b/z}^\infty e^{-zy} y^{-1/2} dy \right )$$

where $a,b$ are free parameters to be tuned for the approximation. Each of these integrals can be expressed in terms of the incomplete Gamma function (for the ones with the logarithms, you start with $u=\ln(y)$).

Comment: the final result shouldn't depend on $a$ and $b$ right?

Comment: @tired The true $\Psi$ of course doesn't depend on $a,b$. The idea here is that you could do further estimation from here to optimize over $a,b$ or at least approximately do so. (The point being that as $a,b$ increase, the error in the first and third terms increases while the error in the second and fourth terms decreases. At some point they should balance.) Ideally you would instead use a composite asymptotic expansion and integrate that, but composite asymptotic expansions are quite difficult to handle.

Comment: i see, thanks for the explanation

Comment: Thanks a lot @Ian for your answer, really helps me ! Do you think it would make a difference if the lower bound of the integral is not 0 but $w/z$, where w<<1? It would really help me solve my problem if the final solution did not depend on a or b, but I'll still give a try.

Comment: Well, it depends on how big the integral on $[0,w/z]$ is. It should not be big, though; indeed you should be able to straightforwardly estimate it.

Answer (score 0):

A possible hint for the FIRST integral (the second one could be quite similar).

$$\Psi_1(z) = \sqrt{z}\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{\ln\left(1 + \frac{e^{-zy}}{y}\right)}{\sqrt{y}}\ \text{d}y$$

Now use the substitution

$$zy = \ln t ~~~~~ \text{d}y = \frac{1}{zt}\ \text{d}t ~~~~~ t = e^{zy}$$

To get

$$\Psi_1(z) = \sqrt{z}\int_1^{+\infty}\ln\left(1 + \frac{e^{-\ln t}}{\frac{1}{z}\ln t}\right)\frac{\text{d}t}{zt} \frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{z}\ln t}}$$

Arranging a bit the terms to get:

$$\Psi_1 (z) = \int_1^{+\infty} \frac{1}{t}\ln\left(1 + \frac{z}{t\ln t}\right)\frac{\text{d}t}{\sqrt{\ln t}}$$

Now perfomr the other substitution

$$\ln t = p^2 ~~~~~ p = \sqrt{\ln t} ~~~~~\text{d}p = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{\ln t}}\frac{1}{t}\ \text{d}p$$

To get:

$$\Psi_1(z) = 2\int_0^{+\infty} \ln\left(1 + \frac{z}{p}e^{-p^2}\right)\ \text{d}p$$

I believe this is (maybe not) the best we can obtain from the first part. Maybe there are more suitable substitutions. I'm on the bus, so I hope I did not write malarkey.

One might try to expand the exponential term (like up to the second order) and give a try of the behaviour.

Otherwise, you might evaluate it with a $\Lambda$ cutoff like

$$\Psi_2(z) = \lim_{\Lambda\to \infty}\int_0^{\Lambda} \ln\left(1 + \frac{z}{p}e^{-p^2}\right)\ \text{d}p$$

For the second term, I'd try something similar.

Once at home, I'll take a deeper look.

**Interesting case: $z = p$**

$$\Psi_2(z = p) = \lim_{\Lambda\to \infty}\int_0^{\Lambda} \ln\left(1 + e^{-p^2}\right)\ \text{d}p = 0.6780938949040456$$